# R's paste function equivalent in BASH?

Tags: r, bash, paste

I'm trying to translate this piece of R code into bash:

```
year <- 2010
emmissions <- paste("Emmision table from ",year, sep="")
em_table <- read.table(emmissions, head=F, as.is=T)

for (i in 1:nrow(em_table)) {
        print(em_table[i,1])
}
```

But can't figure out how to translate paste function to concatenate string with variable. Expected outcome would be this script translated into bash code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using perhaps `echo "Emmision table from  ${year}"` inside your for loop something like below:

```
for var in 2001 2003 2004; 
do 
    echo "Emission table ${var}"
done
```

**Updated on OP's request:**

for sequence generation in bash , one can do : `for i in {1..5}` for a sequence of 1 to 5 or `{0..20..4}` for a step size of 4 from a sequence of 0 to 20

Assuming a column like structure, one can do this:
Assuming a table which has two column saved in a text file

```
col1 col2
1 2
3 4
5 6

while read col1 col2
do
    echo "Col1 : $col1"
    echo "Col2 : $col2"
done < table.txt
```

Comment: This will do. Can you translate second part as well?  (for (i in 1:nrow(em_table)) {
        print(em_table[i,1])}

Given that 'em_table' consists of two columns of numbers

Comment: But how would one then call the file with such name (read.table option in R) and then extract the needed column/row (table[x,w] function in R)?

Comment: @juststuck, didn't get your question.. please elaborate or you can ask a new question detailing what you want...

Comment: In above R code i first do three things: define variable (year), then combine variable with string (_paste_ function) and then by using _read.table_ i get the file with a name generated previously by _paste_ function.

This file consists of numbers arranged in two columns so next step (_for loop_ in my R code) is to extract these numbers from table.

My goal is to replicate such functionality in BASH.

Comment: What if no column names are present?

Comment: @juststuck, doesn't matter it should work, just give two random column names...means the code above will be valid

Answer (score 2):

There already is an accepted answer but here is a awk solution.
Tested with just one file, named `"test2020"`.

```
for var in 2020;
do
  awk '{print $1}' "test${var}"
done
```

Output:

```
1
2
3
```

To read both columns the `awk` code line would be

```
awk '{print $1 $2}' "test${var}"
```

or, since the OP says the files only have two columns,

```
awk '{print $0}' "test${var}"
```

The file contents are:

```
1 a
2 b
3 c
```

Comment: very nice indeed!!! not many know about awk these days..... :)

Comment: @PKumar I liked immediately when I've learned it back in the (early) 1990's.